# Back-channel logout using OIDC

Tags: angular, openid, openid-connect

I'm currently working on Backchannel logout using openid. The flow , as I have understood goes like the following

1- User agent(browser in my case) triggers the logout using a link to the OP.
2- OP deletes the user sessions, and send the loogout token to the RP.
3- RP deletes all user sessions.

Can somebody please tell me how to get the link to OP from the browser to trigger the request in the first place. I am using angular 4 on the front end if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

There is a chapter about [Relying Party (RP) Initiated Logout](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html#RPLogout) in the OpenID Connect Session Management RFC. It says the logout endpoint URL could be obtained from the end_session_endpoint element of the OpenID Provider's (OP)
 [Discovery](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html) response. It's a JSON document usually available at

```
GET ${OP_BASE_URL}/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

If the logout endpoint is not mentioned there, the OP might publish it somewhere else, but it's implementation specific.

The event flow is a bit different:

1. RP log the user out first
2. RP requests the OP to invalidate session of the user using the logout URL
3. OP invalidates the session

Comment: afaik that's the front-channel logout where the user accesses the "end_session_endpoint" which will close the session on the IDP where the backchannel logout, as I understood it, would be if someone logs out directly from the IDP this logout needs to be propagated to all relying parties.